# Rest template throwing HttpClientErrorException - 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm trying to make a post request to another spring app but I'm getting a 404 error.

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromUriString(config.getUrl() +
                        "jobs/create_job");

        log.info("Sending job to api at " + builder.toUriString());

        try {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            HttpEntity<EnrichmentJob> entity = new HttpEntity<>(job, headers);

            return restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.POST,
                    entity, Job.class);
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException ex) {
            log.info("Error creating job " + ex.getResponseBodyAsString());
            throw new EnrichmentException(ex.getResponseBodyAsString(), ex.getStatusCode());
        } catch (ResourceAccessException ex) {
            log.info("Error creating job " + ex.getMessage());
            throw new EnrichmentException(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
            log.info("Error creating job " + ex.getMessage());
            throw new EnrichmentException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getStatusCode());
        }





 2019-01-30 18:46:58.002  INFO 25897 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] c.t.m.c.repository.EnrichmentRepository  : Sending job to api at http://localhost:8080/v1/enrichment_jobs/create_job
    2019-01-30 18:46:58.008  INFO 25897 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] c.t.m.c.repository.EnrichmentRepository  : Error creating job 404 Not Found
    2019-01-30 18:46:58.009  INFO 25897 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] c.t.m.c.l.ApplicationEventListener       : Event ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/enrichment_jobs/v1/create_job]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[dispatcherServlet]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[9ms]; status=[OK]
```

Making a request to this endpoint

```
@PostMapping(path = "/create_job",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Jobs> createJob(
            @RequestBody JobsRequest enrichmentJob)
            throws DuplicateJobException {

        Jobs job = service.convertToJobs(enrichmentJob);
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(
                    service.createJob(job), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (DuplicateJobException ex) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(job, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

    }
```

Logging the url shows that the url is correct and I can successfully use the endpoint with postman. Are there additional headers I need to set?

using postman to the same url:

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/enrichment_jobs/create_job
```

with request body:

```
{
    "status": "IN_PROCESS",
    "host_name": "host",
    "job_type": "UPLOAD",
    "job_id": "3934582d-ed3e-4dr5-86b6-ad17f9ed7543",
    "asset_id": "3934582d-ed3e-4dr5-86b6-ad17f9ed7315"
}
```

creates and returns the resource as expected.

The Job class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class JobsRequest {
    private String jobId;

    private String assetId;

    private String status;

    private String jobType;

    private String hostName;

    private String jobStatus;

    private String createdBy;

    private String lastUpdatedBy;
}
```

Comment: can you also show the postman body and this `job`  in entity

Comment: here is the issue, you should remove the `jobStatus;`,`createdBy;`, and `lastUpdatedBy;` from this class `JobsRequest`

Comment: I still get the same 404 error

Comment: use `JsonProperty` for naming convention, try my answer

Comment: do you have getters and setters to that pojo class?

Comment: Adding JsonProperty to each field worked. I thought `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)` would take care of the naming.